# How to convert currency in a database using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

In my problem one column have type of currency and another have the value, I need to convert them to USD. How can I do that using pandas ?

My Columns as following:-

[image]

I want like this:

[image]

```
from currency_converter import SINGLE_DAY_ECB_URL
last_date = con.bounds['USD']
con = CurrencyConverter(SINGLE_DAY_ECB_URL)


def currency_convertor(row,new_currency='USD'):
    amount = row['Amount']
    curr = row['Currency']
    new_curr = con.convert(amount,curr,new_currency)
    return new_curr

df5 = df5.apply(lambda x: currency_convertor(x,new_currency="USD"), axis=1)
```

BUT after conversion I'm getting only amount column
like this
[image]

I want it as second table

Comment: [CurrencyConverter](https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and show your code. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: if you return only `new_curr` then you should assign to column `df5["Amount"] = ... `. If you want replace also `Currency` then you should return `row` with both `Currency` and `new_curr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer below I'll assume that you have a dataframe, `df`, with columns named `currency` and `amount`.

I have cobbled together a [demo jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/aricooperdavis/4c5bfe087e0e3cb6b68e66d9e30230fc) to illustrate the method.

1. **Work out what currencies you have in your dataframe**

   You'll need an exchange rate for every currency you have in your dataframe, so you need to know what currencies you have.

   ```py
   currencies = df.currency.unique().tolist()
   currencies = dict.fromkeys(currencies, pd.NA)
   ```
2. **Define an exchange rate for every currency**

   Exchange rates vary over time, and can vary depending on who you ask, so you'll need to define a set exchange rate to use. You can define these yourself manually:

   ```py
   currencies['CAD'] = 1.23
   currencies['GBP'] = 0.72
   ```

   Alternatively, as [It_is_Chris pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68103246/how-to-convert-currency-in-a-database-using-pandas#comment120368122_68103246), you could use the [CurrencyConverter](https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/) library to source these automatedly in real time:

   ```py
   from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
   c = CurrencyConverter()
   for key in currencies:
      try:
         currencies[key] = c.convert(1, 'USD', key)
      except:
         pass
   ```
3. **Convert the currencies in your dataframe**

   Try and avoid looping through pandas dataframes; the built in methods are much faster. In this case you can use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

   ```py
   df['amount_conv'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.amount / currencies[x.currency], axis=1 )
   ```

Comment: Hello @Ari Cooper-Davis it's showing
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
And I have updated the question, So can you please check that.

Comment: I meant `apply()` when I wrote `assign()`. I have since edited the answer.

Comment: I'm still getting error
TypeError: apply() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
Sorry I'm a student and new to ML and Data  science. I'm trying to solve this problem but one after another error is showing. Even if I convert the amount it's only printing the amount column not the hole table.....

Comment: Could you copy and paste your version of that line? If you check out the notebook you'll see that it does work without errors, so there must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: Thank You very much......

Comment: After working a lot with other data, I found where I was wrong.
Again thank you very much.